# How to draw polygonal lines in Excalidraw?

Tags: drawing

It's super easy to draw curved lines in Excalidraw, but I couldn't find an easy way of drawing polygonal (straight) lines.

Does anyone know how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select an already drawn object and choose the setting **Edges > Sharp.**

Or draw a new polygonal line directly in this mode.

[image]

Comment: thanks! ... how could I not see that ?  ... also, we need an `excalidraw` tag here, I still don't have the reputation to create it